# Magento 2 Add/Update Product attribute value

Tags: php, magento2

I have an import script that loads a feed, creates custom attributes, and assigns them to sets.

Now I'm looking for a way to add product information to these attributes, preferably by attribute code, so once I have the product model ready I can set the value and save.

```
/**
 * @var Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
 */
protected $_modelProduct;

/**
 * Update product attribute
 *
 * @param integer $productId
 * @param string $attributeCode
 * @param string $value
 */
public function updateProductAttribute($productId, $attributeCode, $value)
{

    $model = $this->_modelProduct
    ->load($productId);

    /* Update product attribute with new value */

}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That one should be working.

```
    $model->addData(array('custom_attribute' => 'foobar'));
    $model->save();
```